# Push an event from a Rest app to a Vaadin app on the same Glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, push, vaadin

What would be the best approach to push a notification or fire an event from a Restful web service based application to a Vaadin based one. Ive tried already JMS however unsuccessfully. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use some interprocess communication for this. JMS is not a bad idea for this and should work for your use case. Just make sure you read about modifying the UI from another thread inn the book of vaadin. https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html#advanced.push.running

Comment: JMS seemed like a natural solution to me as well. i set up a project in Glassfish 4.1 and Vaadin 7.4 but JMS always fails due to some internal exceptions.